# How to remove Google maps default pointers?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, pointers

I need to customize a map to look like this :

[image]

I was managed to add my own pointer icons and change the direction style to dots - but the default pointers are still appears....
Here is my [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/roybarak/sfv80wnt/1/)

Here what I've done so far :

```
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), 
    myOptions),
    directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService,
    directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
        map: map
    }),
    markerA = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: pointA,
        map: map,
        icon:'https://drive.google.com/uc?id=0B3RD6FDNxXbdVXRhZHFnV2xaS1E',
    }),
    markerB = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: pointB,
         map: map,
        icon:'https://drive.google.com/uc?id=0B3RD6FDNxXbdM3E5clBqWDY5MWM',
    });
```

I also would like to know how can i add the kilometers sum as a tooltip that keeps it's position relative to the route - like in the picture, any help will appreciated.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue.  Your fiddle doesn't demonstrate the same behavior as the image.

Comment: geocodezip - thanks - i edited my post - turns out i didn't save the Fiddle..hence it wasn't update...

Answer (score 0):

O.k - i got most of the stuff done, here is the result.

```
function initMap() {

        var lineSymbol = {

        path: "M-20,0a20,20 0 1,0 40,0a20,20 0 1,0 -40,0",
        fillColor: '#3da6f9',
        fillOpacity: 1,
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(0,0),
        strokeWeight: 0,
        strokeOutline:2,
        scale: 0.2
    };
var pointA = new google.maps.LatLng(51.7519, -1.2578),
    pointB = new google.maps.LatLng(50.8429, -0.1313),
    myOptions = {
        zoom: 7,
        center: pointA
    },
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), myOptions),
    // Instantiate a directions service.
    directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService,
    directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
     polylineOptions: {
                strokeColor: '#426289',
                strokeOpacity: 0.4,
                strokeWeight: 5,
                icons: [{
                    icon: lineSymbol,
                    offset: '0px',
                    repeat: '15px'
                }]
            },
            suppressMarkers: true,
            map: map
    }),
    markerA = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: pointA,
        icon: 'https://drive.google.com/uc?id=0B3RD6FDNxXbdVXRhZHFnV2xaS1E',
        map: map
    }),
    markerB = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: pointB,
        icon: 'https://drive.google.com/uc?id=0B3RD6FDNxXbdM3E5clBqWDY5MWM',
        map: map
    });

// get route from A to B
calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay, pointA, 
pointB);

}

  function calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay, 
  pointA, pointB) {
  directionsService.route({
    origin: pointA,
    destination: pointB,
    avoidTolls: true,
    avoidHighways: false,
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
}, function (response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
    } else {
        window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
    }
  });
}

initMap();
```

And here is the [Result](http://jsfiddle.net/roybarak/h54tmmcb/1/)